# How do you update the value returned by a mocked service in angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I have a service method that I'm using to populate a variable in my controller's scope. When I go to test it, I want to be able to mock the service method to return different values so that I can test how the controller responds. To do this I've done the following:

```
var data = 'some data';

ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
  $scope: $scope,
  MyService: {
    getData: function() {
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

And this does return 'some data' when I assert the variable in my scope. However when I change the value of data within my test, the value returned from getData() isn't updated right away.

```
it('should say "more data"', function() {
    data = 'more data';
    expect($scope.data).toEqual(data);
});
```

By setting the data to 'bar', I would expect my scope to be set to 'bar' as well by the mocked getData(), but it still returns 'foo'. What's weird is that if I have another test after this one where I set data to 'baz', then $scope.data is 'bar'. So the value of data is being set, but seems to be just lagging behind by a test. I've tried called scope.$apply() after setting data in my test to no avail.

I know I'm missing something silly, but I can't put my finger on it.

[Issue duplicated on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWrdaUI3UByf80pxPmK7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your controller in each test so that `MyService.getData` is invoked before each assertion.

```
describe('Test app', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;
  var controller = null;
  var _MyService_ = null
  var data = 'some data';

  //mock the service
  angular.module('MyServiceMock', [])
      .value('MyService',{
        getData: function() {
           return data;
        }
      });

  //inject the mock
  beforeEach(module('plunker', 'MyServiceMock'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, MyService) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller; 
    _MyService_ = MyService;
  }));

  it('should say "some data"', function() {
    ctrl = controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      MyService: _MyService_
    });

    expect($scope.data).toEqual(data);
  });

  it('should say "more data"', function() {
    data = 'more data';

    ctrl = controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      MyService: _MyService_
    });

    expect($scope.data).toEqual(data);
  });

  it('should say "even more data"', function() {
    data = 'even more data';

    ctrl = controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      MyService: _MyService_
    });

    expect($scope.data).toEqual(data);
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HcZBQFpAtCoUnEncAkJe?p=preview